# Android - OpenCV BGRA to BGR conversion is very slow

Tags: android, opencv, camera

Currently we are developing a smartphone app to apply filters on camera frames using opencv. Filters need BGR Mat (edgePreservingFilter function), but the camera gives BGRA pictures.

Using `cv::cvtColor(img,img,COLOR_BGRA2BGR)` is working to make the conversion but doing it on each frame make the camera view very slow (0.2 fps in average).

We tried other techniques like manual conversion but everytime the conversion is very slow, and we don't know how to fix it / other methodes more suited to give the correct Mat format.

We are using OpenCV 3.2.0 and Android Studio 2.3.3

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: What is the output of OpenCV function: `getBuildInformation()`?

Comment: output is very long, to summarize I have :
Version control: 3.2.0
Platform:
  Host:   Linux 4.8.0-25-generic x86_64
  Target:  Linux 1 aarch64
  CMake:  2.8.12.2
  CMake generator: Ninja
  CMake build tool: /usr/bin/ninja
  Configuration: Release

Media I/O: 
   ZLib: z (ver 1.2.3)
   JPEG: build (ver 90)
   WEBP: build (ver 0.3.1)
   PNG:  build (ver 1.6.24)
   TIFF: build (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
   JPEG 2000: build (ver 1.900.1)
   OpenEXR: build (ver 1.7.1)
   GDAL: NO
   GDCM: NO

Comment: Put the whole output in a file and upload it to pastebin.com. Post the link here.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/36xg0SHm

Comment: Did you build OpenCV from source?

Comment: I don't think it because we are using the android sdk for opencv (there are only java sources) and it was imported as module in Android Studio and added to dependencies. We didn't use cmake to build anything

Comment: What did you actually measure? Since you give us the frequency, rather than duration, I'd assume that it wasn't just the time required for the call to `cvtColor`. | It would seem rather odd that a conversion which is basically a copy dropping one of the planes would take 5 seconds. Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces this issue.

Comment: @nick I haven't used OpenCV4Android, but I had similar performance issues with OpenCV and Nvidia Tegra. I was using pre-built binaries with general options. After I built OpenCV for my specific hardware with optimizations ON, the performance issue was resolved.

Comment: @Dan Mašek Without the cvtColor BGRA2BGR and with removing the function that require an BGR format Mat, the video stream is very smooth, but once the cvtColor and the function edgePreservingFilter are called, the camera show only one picture every 5 seconds, but I don't think so the issue comes from edgePreservingFilter(). 
https://pastebin.com/0xZAXVYf  :  there are the method onCameraFrame() called at every frame taken by the camera, and the native filter with the conversion cvtColor added (note that cvtColor BGR2GRAY does not create any problem of downturn)

Comment: @zindarod I think this solution is to be tested, thank you for your help, but I would find it strange that only this specific conversion was affected by this opencv version

Comment: @nick Interesting. As a workaround, you could perhaps try to drop the alpha channel with a `split`+`merge` or `mixChannels`.

Comment: edgePreservingFilter (and your function as a whole) is _very_ slow. The conversion itself is pretty fast instead. And, most important, don't assume anything... profile your code!